# Recover a not responding ssh server

Tags: linux, sles, tty

a machine with a postgres database (which is reponding fine) has a ssh service an nagios nrpe service.

Responds to ping.

Postgres is performing as expected. (apache connects from another host)

Nagios  check to port 5432(postgres is ok).

ssh does not connect (as shown above).

Access through tty has the same response as ssh (nothing shown on screen)

What can be done? I's a production server.

THanks.

```
[root@localmachne ~]# ssh remotemachine -vvvvvvvv
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remotemachine [X.Y.Z.T] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
```

Comment: ssh is responding fine (`debug1: Connection established`).  Stop feeding your ssh client a corrupted key and/or use a password to log in.

Comment: If you have side-channel access to the machine, check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files - it might well be that you have placed entries in there which would prevent you from connecting via SSH from where you are trying to.

Comment: Syneticon-dj, I believe that if that were the case, the remote service wouldn't offer him a banner, and no `connection established` would be logged.  I've been wrong before, though!

Answer (score 3):

Your SSH key is corrupted. Connect with password authentication or the console and regenerate your SSH keys (or restore from a backup).